# Django: Deploy to ElasticBeanstalk import error on myapp.settings

Tags: python, django, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm deploying an app to ElasticBeanstalk and am hitting a snag that seems pretty simple. The error is effectively `ImportError: No module named myapp.settings` but I can't figure out what should be causing this issue. I've deployed other django apps with identical settings in the past and haven't had this problem before.

I've attached below the error logs from eb as well as my manage.py and .ebextensions file

`errors from eb logs`

```
[2016-03-07T03:10:29.648Z] INFO  [3559]  - [Application update/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild] : Starting activity...
[2016-03-07T03:10:30.852Z] INFO  [3559]  - [Application update/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild] : Starting activity...
[2016-03-07T03:10:30.853Z] INFO  [3559]  - [Application update/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild/postbuild_0_Myapp] : Starting activity...
[2016-03-07T03:10:31.824Z] INFO  [3559]  - [Application update/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild/postbuild_0_Myapp/Command 01_collectstatic] : Starting activity...
[2016-03-07T03:10:31.894Z] INFO  [3559]  - [Application update/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild/postbuild_0_Myapp/Command 01_collectstatic] : Activity execution failed, because: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Myapp/manage.py", line 10, in <module>
  execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
  utility.execute()
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 302, in execute
  settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 55, in __getattr__
  self._setup(name)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 43, in _setup
  self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 99, in __init__
  mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
  __import__(name)
  ImportError: No module named myapp.settings
   (ElasticBeanstalk::ExternalInvocationError)
```

`manage.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "Sifhub.settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

`.ebextensions/01-django_eb.config`

```
option_settings:
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment":
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: "Myapp.settings"
    PYTHONPATH: "/opt/python/current/app/Myapp:$PYTHONPATH"
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python":
    WSGIPath: "Myapp/Myapp/wsgi.py"
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:staticfiles":
    "/static/": "subapp/static/"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see your django app name is `Sifhub` and your config file contents Myapp as your app name.

Your config file ideally should be like :

```
option_settings:
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment":
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: "Sifhub.settings"
    PYTHONPATH: "/opt/python/current/app/Sifhub:$PYTHONPATH"
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python":
    WSGIPath: "Sifhub/wsgi.py"
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:staticfiles":
    "/static/": "subapp/static/"
```